# Listing contents in c++

Tags: c++, file-io

I have written the following structures.

```
struct RGB
{
     unsigned short Red; 
     unsigned short Green;
     unsigned short Blue;
};

struct ImageBase
{
     std::string name;
     RGB array[64][64];
};
```

I have got a file "Image.png".How  do I read the file(print the RGB values to the screen or file)?

Comment: first u have to know the png file storage format

Comment: Incidentally, do you really mean you want to store 32 file names? Or just 1, which may take up to 32 characters? If it's the second, you just need `std::string name;`.

Comment: Doing this manually would require understanding [the PNG specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/). The next level up would be using [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html). Other libraries, such as [SDL_Image](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/), provide further abstraction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use gil which is part of boost to read the image:

```
using namespace boost::gil;
rgb8_image_t input;
png_read_and_convert_image(ipath, input);
```

You would then create a view on the image to access the pixels, and iterate over the pixels to write them to standard out:

```
rgb8_view_t src_view = view(input);

for (int y=0; y < src_view.height(); ++y) {

    rgb8_view_t::x_iterator src_it = src_view.row_begin(y);

    for (int x=0; x < src_view.width(); ++x)
        std::cout << "R=" << src_it[x][0] << " G=" << src_it[x][1] << " B=" << src_it[x][2] << std::endl;
}
```

Docs for gil are here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/gil/doc/index.html